# Determinate selector of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose that I have some elements with class="A"; How to determinate on which element mouse is over,leave or click, how to get its selector like ".A:eq(n)"?

```
    function TableAns(){
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        var y = '.A:eq('+ i + ')';
        $(y).on({
            click : function(){
                    for(var j = 0; j < 5; j++){
                        var yy = '.A:eq(' + j + ')';
                        var z = i * j;
                        generateTableAns(i,yy,z);
                    }
            $(y).css("border","black solid 3px");
            n = 5;
            TableAnsF(n);
                },
            mouseover : function(){
                $(y).css("border","red solid 3px");
            },
            mouseleave : function(){
                $(y).css("border","black solid 3px");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `this` is the element that triggered the event

Comment: Tried using `$(this).selector` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [getPath](http://davecardwell.co.uk/javascript/jquery/plugins/jquery-getpath/) jQuery plugin.

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    getPath: function( path ) {
       // The first time this function is called, path won't be defined.
       if ( typeof path == 'undefined' ) path = '';

       // If this element is <html> we've reached the end of the path.
       if ( this.is('html') )
           return 'html' + path;

       // Add the element name.
       var cur = this.get(0).nodeName.toLowerCase();

       // Determine the IDs and path.
       var id = this.attr('id'),
           class = this.attr('class');

       // Add the #id if there is one.
       if ( typeof id != 'undefined' )
          cur += '#' + id;

       // Add any classes.
       if ( typeof class != 'undefined' )
          cur += '.' + class.split(/[\s\n]+/).join('.');

       // Recurse up the DOM.
       return this.parent().getPath( ' > ' + cur + path );
   }
});
```

Comment: no need to walk up DOM past an ID since ID's are unique

Comment: This is a jQuery plugin which I did not write.
IDs are unique as long as you keep them unique, but this plugin does not assume that it is the case because it is not crafted for a specific scenario.

Comment: simple way is `$parents().each()` then break the loop if element has ID

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to iterate over them yourself, jquery will that for you. If you need the index of the element, just use `index()`. Now I am not very clear about what you are trying to achieve but you can try something like,

```
$('.A').click(function() {
    var outer_index = $(this).index();
    $('.A').each(function(inner_index) {
        generateTableAns(outer_index, $(this), outer_index*inner_index);    
    });
});
```

Basically `$(this)` is the element that you are iterating over. Use `this`.